# Taking the derivative of $n$ products

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

I'm reading my numerical analysis book, but I don't understand this step:

[image]

I'm assuming that this $l'$ must be $l_0'$, as there is no $l$ defined anywhere. If you want, you can read the text above this step [here](http://mathematics.discoursehosting.net/uploads/db1409/256/e6b6850fe526bb78.png).

I can see why $l_0(x_0)=1$. And why $l(x_i)=0$. But I don't see why $l_0'(x_i)=0$. How do you take the derivative of $n$ products ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple generalisation of the product rule, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule for e.g. 3 factors. $l_0'(x)$ is a sum of $n$ products where each summand contains $(x-x_i)^2$ or $2(x-x_i)$ and therefore $l_0'(x)=0$.

Here an illustration of the above statement, let 
$$f_i(x)=\frac{(x-x_i)^2}{(x_0-x_i)^2},$$
then $l_0(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n f_i(x)$, and for $n=2$ you get
\begin{aligned}
f'_i(x) &= 2\frac{(x-x_i)}{(x_0-x_i)^2}\\
l'_0(x) &= f'_1(x)f_2(x) + f_1(x)f'2(x)\\ 
&=
\frac{2(x-x_1)}{(x_0-x_1)^2}\frac{(x-x_2)^2}{(x_0-x_2)^2}+\frac{(x-x_1)^2}{(x_0-x_1)^2}\frac{2(x-x_2)}{(x_0-x_2)^2}
\end{aligned}
and this is obviouly zero for $x=x_1$ and $x=x_2$.
The complete expression for general $n$ is
$$
l'_0(x) = \frac{2(x-x_1)}{(x_0-x_1)^2}\prod_{i\ne 1}\frac{(x-x_i)^2}{(x_0-x_i)^2}+ \cdots + \frac{2(x-x_n)}{(x_0-x_n)^2}\prod_{i\ne n}\frac{(x-x_i)^2}{(x_0-x_i)^2}
$$
and it is zero for all $x=x_i$.

BTW: The crucial part about $l(x)$ is missing in your picture.